# UIBarButtonItem Image Inset Reapplied Every Time Redrawn?

Tags: ios5, uikit, interface-builder

I have a `UIToolbar` as part of my `UINavigationController`. The `UIToolbar` has several plain `UIBarButtonItem`s on it, each with custom images I specified in interface builder. My images don't fit quite as centered as I'd like, so I apply a small image inset to the top in the size inspector.

[image: UIToolbar]

The button on the left has no inset, and the one on the right has an inset on the top of 6.

However, it seems that whenever the toolbar is redrawn (after coming back from a modal view, or hiding and unhiding the toolbar), the button with an inset shrinks more and more—like the inset is getting reapplied every time. So it looks like this:

[image: Messed up UIToolbarButtonItem]

Is this a bug in iOS, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with an iPhone app specifically when returning from a modal view. The way I handled it was to fire off an NSNotification when the Modal is being dismissed that the views which were having issues would listen to. Kinda Like this.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"DismissingModal" object:nil];
```

Then register it in your other class to fire your method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(drawRect:) name:@"DismissingModal" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

When are you adjusting the inset for your image?  If you are doing it in ViewWillAppear (or ViewDidAppear), that method is being called again when the modal is being dismissed.

Perhaps you can make the inset adjustment in ViewDidLoad instead?